# Unable to register major mode

Tags: emacs, elisp, syntax-highlighting, text-editor, major-mode

I have a major mode I created at https://github.com/secondplanet/elixir-mode/blob/master/elixir-mode.el, but when I require it in my `~/.emacs`, and then try to type `M-x elixir-mode`, I'm told the function does not exist. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misspelled "interactive" in elixir-mode.

Comment: Thanks! I entirely missed that.

Comment: @secondplanet: FYI, emacs will catch some things like this if you byte compile (`M-x emacs-lisp-byte-compile`) your files. In this case it will say something like `Warning: the function \`interctive' is not known to be defined.`